# Is there a way to create an usage plan per api key for AWS Api Gateway in serverless?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

In [official docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/) only has the default configuration with a list of API Keys and only one Usage Plan. All API keys are connected to that single usage plan.

Is there a way to configure separate usage plan for each API key in **serverless framework**?

Comment: Until today this issue appears that does not have a solution yet.

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3182

Answer (score 2):

Now, it's available as part configuration and detailed out [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#setting-api-keys-for-your-rest-api)

```
service: my-service
provider:
  name: aws
  apiKeys:
    - free:
        - myFreeKey
        - ${opt:stage}-myFreeKey
    - paid:
        - myPaidKey
        - ${opt:stage}-myPaidKey
  usagePlan:
    - free:
        quota:
          limit: 5000
          offset: 2
          period: MONTH
        throttle:
          burstLimit: 200
          rateLimit: 100
    - paid:
        quota:
          limit: 50000
          offset: 1
          period: MONTH
        throttle:
          burstLimit: 2000
          rateLimit: 1000
functions:
  hello:
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/create
          method: get
          private: true
```